# Is this question I want to ask, off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I can't seem anywhere else (currently active or even from a quick glance, in Area51?) more closely related than here to ask this question. I actually intend to answer it myself, as an info resource for the benefit of the Internet when people google or search on stackexchange.

It's this:

'Are there any non-chlorinated pools in London?'

I intend to compile rare information for it and it's of course related to fitness in a *general* way, but if you guys deem it not related enough to it in terms of physical training then I'll not post it but try and find somewhere else suitable to post it on the Internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you're asking this question in the right place!

I'm leaning towards off-topic, even though Too Localized is no longer available as a closing reason. On the one hand, perhaps there's lots of people (out of the millions living in London), who would be interested in this information. But you'd need a question like this for every city someone is interested in, because its so limited geographically.

Yet, I don't expect tons of people to show up and start asking the same question for their home town, so perhaps I'm just imagining the worst. So perhaps it would actually be better to go for it and deal with any issues when and if they arise.

Comment: I sadly have to agree with this, as it is also localised in time. What is non-chlorinated now may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be on-topic here, but from my experience, this sort of question can work really well for a Subreddit associated with a city.